# How to avoid audio output switching from remote_submix to speaker when the microphone is turned on？

Tags: android, android-source, android-audiorecord, android-audio

**Background**

I have two Android phones. One is the Server and the other is the Client.
I can flash my own images on these two phones by modifying the aosp source code. So I can record from device remote_submix.

Server: record from remote_submix and send audio data to client.

Client: play audio data from server.

**Problem**

When I open the microphone on the server, the sounds will be played on the server's device speaker and the Client lost sound.

By use `dumpsys audio` find that the Devices of STREAM_SYSTEM, STREAM_MUSIC, STREAM_XXX are changed from remote_submix to speaker, and the mode changed from MODE_NORMAL to MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION.

I think this problem may be related to AudioPolicy.
However, Android's audio system is so large and complicated and I couldn't figure it out for a long time.

How to avoid audio output switching from remote_submix to speaker when the microphone is turned on？

Does anyone know any clue about it? Thanks a lot.